# why the grammar can generate a string but cannot be recognised by the same recursive descent parser?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, recursive-descent

For example, we have a grammar S-> aSa | aa, clearly, this grammar can generate all even-length string of a's. If we devise a recursive-descent parser for this grammar, why inputs like "aa", "aaaa", "aaaaaaaa" can be recognized, but "aaaaaa" cannot be recognized?

Here is my thought:

For "aa", try S-> aSa, 'a' matches, however, 'S' does not match, backtrace.
          try S-> aa， matches.

For "aaaa", try S-> aSa, 'a' matches, try S->aSa, we have aaSaa, S not matches, try S->aa, we have aaaa, matches.

For "aaaaaa", try S-> aSa, 'a' matches, try S->aSa, we have aaSaa, try S->aSa, we have aaaSaaa, not matches, try S->aa, we have "aaaaaa".

i don't know what's with the 'aaaaaa' part.

why aaaaaa cannot be recognized?

Comment: Is it a given that `aaaaaa` can not be matched and you want to understand why or are you unable to write a recursive descent parser that can match `aaaaaa`? (i.e. is this is a course assignment or something else)

Comment: i want to understand why aaaaaa cannot be recognized by this recursive descent. @mpkorstanje

Comment: @mpkorstanje: OK, although it seems a bit thin for an answer.

Comment: You changed the question in a way that makes existing answer(s) seem inappropriate (rici is a pretty smart guy; I think his answer was appropriate to the original question).  That ruins the value of the question/answer pair for other readers.  If your original SO question was answered, and you have a new one (apparantly), you should ask that as a new question. *I almost never do this, but in this case I've reverted the question to its original state.*  Please ask your new question, as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Because backtracking is not allowed in a simple recursive descent parser.

Recursive descent parsers read tokens left to right, reading each token once.

Of course you can recognize it with a backtracking recursive descent parser; but then the parser is no longer linear time.